# Logstash csv input output to elastic search

Tags: logstash

I'm new to **Logstash** and I want to visualize some **csv** data using *Logstash* and **Elasticsearch** and **Kibana**.

My *csv* format looks like this :

```
        * Level 2 SMS *
[APAC] tre Alerts Feed is SEVERE on dtryee  (rajdhani-apac)
Date/Time: 2014.07.31 13:45:32
Last Value: SEVERE
Event age: 50m,sent,Thu  31 Jul 2014 03:45:47 +0000,2010-04-01,1,A***********,S************,outbound-api,+1234567,+876543287,-0.02300,USD
```

Am using conf file as following :

```
input {
    file {
        path => ["/opt/sms_log.csv"]
        start_position => "beginning"
    }
}
filter {
    csv {
        columns => ['body', 'status', 'SentDate',  'ApiVersion', 'NumSegments', 'AccountSid', 'Sid', 'Direction', 'From', 'To', 'Price', 'PriceUnit']
    }
}
output {
  elasticsearch { host => localhost }
}
```

I'm not getting the desired output. Can anybody have a look at these and provide me with a piece of advice?

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably want to get the data from `Event age:`

If yes, you have to use `grok` filter first to parse the `Event age` and meet csv format!
For example, you have to `grok` out the data and put it at a field, ex: `csv_data`

> 50m,sent,Thu  31 Jul 2014 03:45:47 +0000,2010-04-01,1,A***********,S************,outbound-api,+1234567,+876543287,-0.02300,USD

Then, in your csv filter you have to specfic the source field:

```
filter {
    csv {
        columns => ['body', 'status', 'SentDate',  'ApiVersion', 'NumSegments', 'AccountSid', 'Sid', 'Direction', 'From', 'To', 'Price', 'PriceUnit']
        source => "csv_data"
    }
}
```

FYI

Comment: no i want the whole data .* Level 2 SMS *
[APAC] tre Alerts Feed is SEVERE on dtryee  (rajdhani-apac)
Date/Time: 2014.07.31 13:45:32
Last Value: SEVERE
Event age: 50m,sent,Thu  31 Jul 2014 03:45:47 +0000,2010-04-01,1,A***********,S************,outbound-api,+1234567,+876543287,-0.02300,USD

Comment: OK, you have to filter all the "\n" because in the csv format, '\n' means new line.